# Вычисление функции с помощью рядов Тейлора

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, ряды

Функция sin(x).
Программа должна выводить на экран количество вычисленных членов ряда, сумму отрезка ряда (аппроксимированное значение функции), достигнутую точность (модуль последнего вычисленного члена ряда) и модуль разности полученной аппроксимации и эталонной (вычисленной с помощью функции и math.h).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раскладываете синус в ряд Тейлора, получится бесконечная сумма. Компьютер не может вычислить бесконечную сумму, поэтому вы ограничиваете сумму сверху, считая сумма до некоторого числа N. Соответственно получаете погрешность, которую можно оценить. По сути вам нужны две функции: одна получает необходимую точность и возвращает нужное N, чтобы точность была достигнута, а вторая считает сумму до полученного N, дальше выводите всё что вам нужно на экран